HP printer under 24.04 not seen
I performed an upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 via Software Updater.  The Brother printer here, connected over our local WLAN, works under 24.04 the same as under 22.04 .  I just did the same upgrade elsewhere but with a HP LaserJet Pro MFP M225dw as the "wifi" connected printer. The printer is not seen and MATE Control Center -> Administration does not have -> Printers (unlike the Brother WIFI printer on a 24.04 system that does have MATE Control Center -> Administration -> Printers).  hplip is the recommended application but 24.04 is NOT (yet?) supported.  I have looked at hplip on 24.04 but this has not worked as far as I can tell (although the instructions therein are minimal).  I have tried to find instructions for manually installing a "wifi" LAN printer without a GUI -- a manual CUPS or other (more current?) interface, not necessarily HP specific, but could not find anything current.  Again, note that 24.04 does not detect a printer; no printer configuration GUI or choice, using MATE desktop on standard 22.04, not MATE Ubuntu.

Please install hplip with sudo apt install hplip and try again

if you spin up a bootable USB of 24.04.1 can it see the printer? I have the same HP series printer and it sees it perfectly well (but that is not using the MATE desktop of course). You may need to consider filing a bug report. Also review https://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/454/builds/310891/buginstructions

Graham,  Are you using a wired (USB) or wifi (802.11) to the printer?
